# Select child element from different containers

Tags: html, css

Hello I would like to know how I can select every second div from different containers. Here is my structure:

```
<div class="bodyarea">
<div class="show">
    <div class="bigthumb">
    <div class="after"></div>
</div>
<div class="show">
<div class="bigthumb">
    <div class="after"></div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

I would like to be able to select each second .after div and apply different style, probably something like that but it is not working. Any idea how this can be realized ?

```
.bodyarea .show .bigthumb .after:nth-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 255px;
    width: 100%; 
    display: block; 
}

.bodyarea .show .bigthumb .after:nth-child(2n) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 265px;
    width: 100%; 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Fix your HTML please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `nth-child` on the parent like

```css
.bodyarea .show:nth-child(1) .bigthumb .after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
.bodyarea .show:nth-child(2) .bigthumb .after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodyarea">
  <div class="show">
    <div class="bigthumb">
      <div class="after"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="show">
      <div class="bigthumb">
        <div class="after"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```